# Probability Poisson sample mean convergency

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, descriptive-statistics

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be a random sample of Pois$(1)$. Then: $$P\left(F\left(\bar X_n\right)<F(1)\right) = P\left(\bar X_n<1\right) \to 1/2$$ as  $n \to \infty$. Is this true and if so, why or why not?

Comment: What is $\bar{X}_n$?

Comment: The sample mean. So: (X1+...+Xn)/n

Comment: The second thing is just a case of the central limit theorem. For the first thing you may need to think a little: $F$ (the Poisson(1) CDF, I assume) is monotone, so that $x \leq y$ implies $F(x) \leq F(y)$, but $F$ is not *strictly* monotone, so $x<y$ does not imply $F(x)<F(y)$. For illustration, $F((n+1)/n)=F(1)$ but $(n+1)/n>1$.